# Sequentially Animate Changing Density Plots in R with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am attempting to create an animation to show how the density for a normal distribution of data changes every time a new sample is added to a data set and the mean and standard deviation are updated.  I have attempted to use the gganimate package and almost have what I'm looking for, but I cannot get the correct sequence in the animation.  I'm fairly certain this is an obvious solution that's staring me right in the face so appreciate any help that can be provided.

A sample data frame can be recreated with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

sampled_data <- data.frame(Group = rep("A", 14),
                           week = c(0,2:5,7:14,20),
                           mean = c(30, 24.76111, 28.02916, 29.1741, 26.75879, 29.80132, 30.33864, 32.02787, 30.39993, 31.53138, 33.36167, 33.64898, 33.25587, 32.76954),
                           st_dev = c(10, 8.518451, 7.524797, 7.048826, 6.242289, 5.490741, 5.247176, 4.757057, 4.34478, 4.034823, 3.680196, 3.569206, 3.455505, 3.317643))

n = 20000

plot_df <- sampled_data %>% 
  uncount(n) %>% 
  mutate(value = rnorm(n(), mean, st_dev)) %>%
  select(Group, week, value)
```

This will give you a data frame that can be fed into ggplot for overlaying the densities with `geom_density`.

```
plot_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, fill = as.factor(week))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 1)
```

[image]

The gganimate option that gets the closet to my intent is `transition_reveal`.

```
plot_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, fill = as.factor(week))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 1) +
  transition_reveal(week)
```

[image]

The issue with the gif animation is that the weeks are not "revealed" in sequential order on top of each other.  When I attempted to order the factor with `seq_along()` in the plot aesthetic, `ggplot(aes(x=value, fill = seq_along(as.factor(week))))`, it removed the color fill from the plots and essentially turned the animation into a wireframe making the visualization useless for instruction purposes.

My ultimate goal is to have the weeks "reveled" on the plot in sequential order with the latest week on top of all previous weeks in the data set and retain the color fill.  Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Comment: This strikes me as a bug in `gganimate`. (Not sure why you would order a factor using `seq_along`, that is not what `seq_along` does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `gganimate`, since the plotting order appears to be correct (i.e. last week on top) before applying the transition.

However, an alternative method *does* work:

```
plot_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, fill = as.factor(week))) +
  geom_density(alpha = 1) +
  transition_time(week) +
  shadow_mark()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I change to `transition_time(week) + shadow_mark()` I get the following error:  Error in transform_path(all_frames, states[[i]], ease, nframes[i], !!id, : transformr is required to tween paths and lines.  I'll have to dig in and see what might be causing this.

Comment: Install the transformr package.